# Configuring an NSPredicate with multiple conditions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, core-data

I'm not certain how one would go about "cascading" several conditions into an NSPredicate.

I'm fairly new to Core Data and not sure if that's the right way to achieve what I am looking to do.

Here is what I am trying to do:

There is a Photo object that has a whereTook relationship to a Location object, which has an inverse of photosTookThere.

The Photo in turn has an NSNumber attribute called isFavourite.

I'd like to configure an NSFetchRequest that will first check that photosTookThere exists and if so, check each resulting Photo object and return only the ones that are set as favourites.

Here is the code so far:

```
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Location" inManagedObjectContext:context];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject[NSSortDescriptorsortDescriptorWithKey:@"locationId" ascending:YES]];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"photosTookThere.@count != 0"];
```

How would I cascade the second condition into the predicate and return the correct results?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Just put each condition inside of parentheses and connect them with AND.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(photosTookThere.@count != 0) AND (isFavourite == %@)", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

I'd also recommend changing the name of your "whereTook" relationship to "location", and your "photosTookThere" to simply "photos", that's more in line with convention.

Comment: Thanks, I'll bear the comment about conventions in mind for the future - I'm new to Core Data.

I still have a problem with the AND though:

    2011-05-15 17:52:24.346 CL Places[14321:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath isFavourite not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Location id=1>'


I'm guessing that's because isFavourite is on the Photo object, not the Location.

photosTookThere is an NSSet. How do I tell the predicate that this is an NSSet and that isFavourite should be checked on each member of the set?

Comment: I see.  Yeah the problem is that one argument is for locations and the other for photos.  I think your naming of the relations mess me up.  If I understand you correctly, then you will be fetching for photos, so your NSEntityDescription should be reflecting that.  What you will want to do is have the location object on hand that you are querying for.  You would then change the predicate to @"(whereTook == %@) AND (isFavourite == %@)", [self location], [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES].   With [self location] being replaced with wherever you have the location object.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks; still having a bit of bother but I'm going to do some additional background reading just in case I'm missing something really obvious. I might even rename the relations so they conform to the proper conventions whilst I'm at it.

Answer (score 8):

I eventually was able to solve this using a subquery:

```m
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                         @"(photosTookThere.@count !=0) AND SUBQUERY(photosTookThere, $Photo, $Photo.isFavourite==1).@count >0"
                         ];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can very simply use AND and OR in your predicate much like you would if you were specifying a "where" condition in an SQL statement.  To check for a NULL, which it looks like you want when comparing against "whereTook", you can compare to nil (whereTook = nil).

Comment: you mean (whereTook == nil). otherwise its an assignment.

Comment: @katzenhut A single ```=``` is a valid conditional for predicates/SQLite.